# Parse JSON using javascript and get specific value in array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, parsing

In my console log the array look like this:

```
{"userid":"5502","fullname":"My fullname","email":"sample@yahoo.com","user_access":"real"}
```

Now on my ajax, I have a handle code for the data array that the server sends to the app:

```
function handleData(responseData) {
    var access = responseData;

    console.log(access);
    if (access == '"real"') {
        alert("Welcome");
        location.href = "home.html";
    } else {
        alert("Your username and password didn\'t match.");
    }
}
```

How I can get the specific value of this `"user_access":"real"` in array and use it in condition.

like this:

```
if (access == '"real"') { // What should be the format of access variable?
    alert("Welcome");
    location.href = "home.html";
}
```

Comment: if (access.access  == "real") ....

Comment: `responseData.access === 'real'`

Comment: That is not an array but object..Use [`Property accessors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access the property of `object`

Comment: @VladuIonut When I try to display it in console log, it is undefined.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is undefined when I try to diplay it on console log. It should display "real".

Comment: What do you get when you log `responseData` then?

Comment: @evolutionxbox {"user_id":"5502","user_fullname":"My fullname","user_email":"sample@yahoo.com","user_access":"real"}

Comment: Is it a string or an object? (Does it have surrounding `"`?)

Comment: @evolutionxbox No it don't have ". Just {} open close bracket.

Comment: Your question (the example object) is inaccurate. You've asked how to check the `access` property, when you actually wanted the `user_access` property.

Comment: @evolution, yes my wrong inputting the real object I used on my code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function handleData(responseData) {
                var response = JSON.parse(responseData);//assuming you are getting the response as a string

                var access = response.user_access;    
                console.log(access);

                if (access == "real") {
                    alert("Welcome");
                    location.href = "home.html";    
                } else {
                    alert("Your username and password didn\'t match.");
                }    
            }//handleData()
```

Normally, we want our response to be in json ( or we can say 'object' ) form, so that we can easily access its inner properties. So, if it's already an object, you do not need to use `JSON.parse`. You can directly access any property like this - `responseData.user_access` . But if it's in string form, then you have to use `JSON.parse()` first to parse the string into JSON ( or object ) format.

Comment: console.log(access); it is undefined.

Comment: can you please paste the output of these two lines:
console.log( responseData ) ;
console.log( typeof responseData );

Comment: console.log( responseData ) ; --> {"user_id":"5502","user_fullname":"My fullname","user_email":"sample@yahoo.com","user_access":"real"}        console.log( typeof responseData ); --> string

Comment: ok, so it does not have `access` property, but `user_access`. I have updated my answer accordingly. Please try once again.

Comment: Hi @Mike,sorry just got back to work. It is working now thank you for helping me out. My mistake I write wrong object on my example. It should be user_access not access.

Comment: so if it's a string I should use JSON.parse. What if it not a string?

Comment: @c.k I have edited the answer and added the case if it's not a string.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Really a great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not surrounded by "" around the {} brackets then just do

```
function handleData(responseData) {
    var access = responseData.access;
    if (access === 'real') {
        alert("Welcome");
        location.href = "home.html";
    } else {
        alert("Your username and password didn\'t match.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is undefined when I try to display (access) it in console log.